# Render Object properties in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a object like this

```
export const otherInformation = [
{
    "FAQ": ['Getting started guide', 'Selling policy'],
    "Help & Support": ['Help guide', 'Selling policy'],
    "Legal": ['Terms of Use', 'Privacy Policy']
}]
```

My code

```
class Information extends Component {
    render() {
        const otherInformationLoop = otherInformation.map((value, key) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
                        <div className="dashboard-info">

                            {Object.keys(value).map((val, k) => {
                                return (<h4 k={k}>{val}</h4>)
                                })
                            }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            { otherInformationLoop }
            // <div></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Im having trouble looping through the object.

Error obtained is like this

`Information.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object`

How can I loop thorugh the object so that the obtained result is obtained

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are rendering an array but you can only return a single block from your react component, wrap your map function within a div

```
class Information extends Component {
    render() {
        const otherInformationLoop = otherInformation.map((value, key) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
                        <div className="dashboard-info">

                            {Object.keys(value).map((val, k) => {
                                return (<h4 k={k}>{val}</h4>)
                                })
                            }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (

            <div>{ otherInformationLoop }</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the render method returned an object with a single otherInformationLoop property. Just returning that value, without any parentheses of any kind would work in React 16+ (but needs a key prop on each outer div).