# Display Axios-Response

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I want to display the results of may **api-call** with react. My api returns a JSON Object:

```
0:{produkt_id: 1, produktname: "Bauernbrot", preis: "4"}
1:{produkt_id: 2, produktname: "Nussbrot", preis: "4.50"}
2:{produkt_id: 3, produktname: "Dinkelbrot", preis: "4.20"}
```

It works if my react component looks like that:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bread: ' '
    };
  }

 componentDidMount(){
    axios
      .post('/api/produkte')
      .then((res)=> {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState(
          { bread: res.data.produkte[0].produktname }
        );
      })
      .catch((err)=> {})
  }
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.bread}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}
```

As I am using Redux, i would like to make that request with a redux-action. This action should update my "products" state in my redux store, that i will display in my react component. Unfortunately I can't get that working.

Here is my action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_PRODUCTS } from './types';

export function setProducts(products) {
  return {
    type: GET_PRODUCTS,
    products
  };
}

export function updateProducts() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios
    .post('/api/produkte')
    .then( res => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch(setProducts(res.data.produkte[0].produktname));
    })
    .catch((err)=> {})
  }
}
```

And my reducer (imported in root reducer):

```
import {GET_PRODUCTS} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  products: {}
};

export default (state=initialState,action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {
        products: action.products
      }
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

If i call my function "updateProducts()" in Constructor of my react component, I can't see that action being executed in my redux store. :(

Comment: can you show the component from where you are dispatching the action, also are you using redux-thunk as a middleware while creating the store. Also see this answer on how to loop through an object and render it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/reactunable-to-loop-through-object/43721237#43721237

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
i am using redux-thunk as a middleware in my store.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import BestellForm from './BestellForm';
import { updateProducts } from '../../redux/actions/getProducts';

class BestellSeite extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BestellForm updateProducts={updateProducts}/>
    );
  }
}

export default connect (null, { updateProducts })(BestellSeite);
```

And:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './bestellSeite.css';
import moment from 'moment';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class BestellForm extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bread: ' '
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.updateProducts();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(updateProducts());
  }
```

did the trick