# React js simple get json and list contents "TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am new to React js and not javascript developer but can hack my way to solutions.

I have Django API url that is delivering simple array. I can successfully use `axios.get` to retrieve url json. But I cannot figure out how to use `map` to render the array contents as a simple list.

I get `"TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function"`

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8800/?format=json')
          .then(result => {
            this.setState({ items: result.data });
          });

    }

    render () { 
        return <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item =>
            <li>{item} </li>)}
        </ul>
    }
}

export default App;
```

The response from `axios.get` is like this:

```
{
"users":"http://localhost:8800/users/?format=json",
"photos":"http://localhost:8800/photos/?format=json",
"teams":"http://localhost:8800/teams/?format=json"
}
```

I would like to render this as a HTML list:

```
users - http://localhost:8800/users/?format=json,
photos - http://localhost:8800/photos/?format=json,
teams - http://localhost:8800/teams/?format=json
```

The solution seems to be rewriting this part of code.

```
render () { 
    return <ul>
      {this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
        <li key>{item} </li>)}
    </ul>
}
```

I have seen many similar questions and answers but there are such as surprising variety of different situations and none apply to my specific case.

Can someone please point out:

a)  what I am missing and 
b) what general React and/or javascript principle it relates to and 
c) any documentation where I could have understood this on my own?

Comment: What you posted in `The json array is like this:` is actually an object and objects don't have `map` function. Please post example of response received from `http://localhost:8800/?format=json`. So probably you need you change your render function to `this.state.items.users.map....`

Comment: Also, I don't think you're actually parsing the JSON. I think there should be a `.then(response => response.json())` immediately after your `axios.get` command and before you `setState`.

Comment: As @AlexandrFedotov already said your API result is an object and not an array and in order to loop through object and render it, you could use the Object.keys() function map over the result. See this answer for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/reactunable-to-loop-through-object/43721237#43721237

Comment: Updated post to reflect that what I called the JSON was actually the response from `axios.get`. Ok so my response is not JSON but an Object. Will try Object.keys() to loop through and render the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` Object keys

`Object.keys(this.state.items)` will return an array of keys `["users", "photos", "teams"]` and then you can `map` this array

It will be better to load your data before component rendered

https://jsfiddle.net/qnqeL65b/

Change `componentDidMount()` on `componentWillMount()`

```
render () { 
    return (
        <ul>
        {
            Object.keys(this.state.items).map(key => {
                return (
                    <li>
                        {key} - {this.state.items[key]}
                    </li>
                )
            }
        }
        </ul>
    )
}
```

[Array.prototype.map() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Object.keys() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I get message ` 'key' is not defined` for line `{key} - {this.state.items}`

Comment: I made some changes (forgot braces after `<ul>` tag and before `</ul>`) and added an example on jsfiddle

Comment: Ok, mapping the object keys worked (even using `componentDidMount` ). Note that the jsfiddle has correct brace and parentheses eg after `</li>` should be `})` instead of `)}`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `Object` does not have a map function. Instead you can do something like this:

```
Object.keys(this.state.items).map((key, index) => {
   // do something
});
```

Or also you can use a `for in` loop:

```
for (let key in this.state.items) {
    // do something
}
```

If you're looking for `key, value` access, give this a try.

```
const obj = { 
  "first": "hello", 
  "second": "goodbye"
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key}, ${value}`);
}

// "first, hello"
// "second, goodbye"
```

Comment: Aren't "key" and "index" the same thing? I see other examples use different terms eg `Object.keys(value).map((val, k)` where val = value and k = key. Do you mean "key" = value and "index" = key?

Comment: Ok answered for myself. For others, from [here](https://javascript.info/object)  _An object can be created with figure brackets {…} with an optional list of properties. A property is a “key: value” pair, where key is a string (also called a “property name”), and value can be anything._