# Rendering a list of nested objects in Reacts

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of objects:

```
const products2 = [
    {category: "Category 1", products:
        {
            product1: "1",
            product2: "2"
        }
    },
    {category: "Category 2", products:
        {
            product1: "3",
            product2: "4"
        }
    },
]
```

How can I render it in a div?
Tried to map it but it didn't work :(

Thanks,
Kuba

Comment: What are you trying to render? Category names? product names? Both?

Comment: Something like:
Category 1
1
2
Category 2
1
2

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/loop-through-an-object-in-react/43721237#43721237 and ahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374572/how-to-render-an-array-of-objects-in-react/41374730#41374730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`products` is an array so `map` over it should be fine. `products` on the other hand is not and therefore `map` won't work. You can use, for example, `Object.values(products2[0].products)` so you get `1` and `2` in an array and do what you need with it.

```js
const products2 = [
  {
    category: "Category 1",
    products: {
      product1: "1",
      product2: "2"
    },
  },
  {
    category: "Category 2",
    products: {
      product1: "3",
      product2: "4"
    },
  },
]

const result = products2
  .map(product => `${product.category} ${Object.values(product.products).join(' ')}`)


console.log(result)
```

Same applies in a react component:

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>
        {products2
          .map(product =>
            <div>
              {product.category}
              {Object.values(product.products).map(name => <p>{name}</p>)}
            </div>
          )
        }
     </div>
   )
}
```

*PS: You don't need to map twice as I did. Mapping only once and returning the div right away is also fine.*

Comment: Great thank you! and how abut:
    <div>Category 1</div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</>
<div>Category 2</div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</>

Comment: Awesome! is it also possible to use conditioner rendering with that? I've got a text in props from a search bar. I tried to use "...indexOf(searchText)<0 return false" but it doesn't work

Comment: @JakubMatwiejew yes, it is possible. Check [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator) docs. They have an explanation around conditional rendering :)