# React - creating checkboxes based on data from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state

I have a problem with implementing one of my ideas. Basically I want to create (in React) small app that:

1) Takes data from object, for example:

```
const obj = {
    person1: {
        name: 'Jessica',
        age: 25
    },
    person2: {
        name: 'Kate',
        age: 27
    },
    person3: {
        name: 'Lisa',
        age: 29
    }
};
```

But count of the attributes can be different than 3 (solution should be flexible).

2) Creates checkboxes with labels (names from the obj).

3) Has 2 buttons: one to check all of the checkboxes and second to deselect them.

4) Shows age when one (or more) of the users are selected, hides when not.

Seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't do it. First problem that I've encountered is how to iterate through object when creating checkboxes. forEach or map don't work. Any tips will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must check this on how to map over object properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/render-object-properties-in-react/43721237#43721237

Comment: Thanks! This and first answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
   const person = obj[key];
});
```

This should get you started. You should probably do some reading on how to work with datastructures.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! Thanks to it I did everything except point 4. I will do it later on and ask if I'll face new problems.