# ReactJS Socket.io Convert json.stringify to json object

Tags: json, reactjs, sockets

JSON.Parse throws errors!
I am currently passing data in through a socket, and I can successfully read the data, but using it as a json object is giving me a lot of troubles. Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: false,
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state;
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on("message", mi => this.setState({ response: mi }));
  }
  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;
    const data = response.cc
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {
            JSON.stringify(data)
          }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I am using jsonfile to read the file and check for changes, if so, push them through. Without using the JSON.stringify function, the page I am currently working in throws an error " If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: mention the full data, and error you mentioned, is very common, you will find many solutions, check "How to render object properties in ReactJS".

Comment: So the data is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ this. I am trying to learn sockets and found this to be a good starting point. Will search and see what I find, thank you

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/render-object-properties-in-react/43721237#43721237, you might not need to stringify JSON data and render

Comment: @ImranChowdhry its an array, so for each item what property you want to render?

Comment: @MayankShukla I just want the coin rank name and price_usd for the coins in the list. I've gotten the map function to work while manually loading the json file in the same component, but it doesn't update anything. This way I have updates values but I can't render it the way I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it is throwing the error is, because the initial value is boolean, and you are trying to run loop on any property of boolean, Here:

```
const { response } = this.state;   // response = false
const data = response.cc           // data will be undefined
data.map(.....)                    // can't read property map of undefined
```

**Solution:**

1- One option is skip the rendering until you didn't get the data from server.

Like this:

```
render(){
    if(!this.state.response)
        return <div>Loading...</div>

    return(....)
}
```

2- Other option is, define the response as an `object` instead of `boolean` in the state, and use `|| []` with `response.cc`.

Like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: {},
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
    };
}
```

Render the array using [#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), Like this:

```
render() {
    const { response } = this.state;
    const data = response.cc || [];
    return (
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {
            data.map(el => (
                <div key={el.id}>
                    <p>Rank: {el.rank}</p>
                    <p>Price: {el.price_usd}</p>
                </div>
            ))
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much!! This worked! Why does the "|| [ ]" allow it to work? Everything else made sense and I am very much appreciative for your help

Comment: because if `response={}`, then response.cc will be undefined, `|| []` will assign the default value as an blank array to response.cc, and it will work.

Comment: Ah, ok makes sense. Very helpful to have a fresh pair of eyes :)

Comment: glad, it helped you :)