# how to print the elements value inside an object react using es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have an array of objects and i want to print the content of each element inside this each object, i have tried the method provided in this([Render Object properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/render-object-properties-in-react)) and what i got is just a list of the elements without its values

```
state={
  machines: [{
        MachineName: 'A1',
        region: 'west', 
        zones:'west-01',
        ipAddr:'1.1.1.1',
        subnet:'test'}, 
      {
        MachineName: 'A2',
        region: 'west', 
        zones:'west-01',
        ipAddr:'1.1.1.2',
        subnet:'test2'

}]

}
      render() {
const machinespc=this.state.machines.map((value,key)=>{

  return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-md-4" key={key}>
            <div className="dashboard-info">

                {Object.keys(value).map((val, k) => {
                    return (<h4 k={k}>{val}</h4>)
                    })
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

})
  return (
```

{machinespc}
              )

and the out put was like below,

```
    MachineName
    region 
    zones
    ipAddr
    subnet
```

so what i want is to print the values of each element inside the object like below:

```
     A1
    west
    west-01
    1.1.1.1
    test'}
```

Comment: Object.keys returns an array of key names, therefore, your return line should look like `return (<h4 k={val}>{value[val]}</h4>)`. Maybe naming your variables with meaningful names would have helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Issue is you are running loop of keys, so you need to use that key to get the value, Like this:

```
{
    Object.keys(value).map((val, k) => <h4 k={k}>{value[val]}</h4>)
}
```

Or you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), it will return the array of all the values, like this:

```
{
    Object.values(value).map((val, k) => <h4 k={k}>{val}</h4>)
}
```

Check this snippet, you will get a better idea:

```js
let obj = {a:1, b:2};

console.log("keys array = ", Object.keys(obj));

console.log("values array = ", Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use Object.entries:

```
{Object.entries(value).map(([key, value]) => {
      return (<h4>{key} : {value}</h4>);
}) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to lookup the value from your `val`:

```
{Object.keys(value).map((val, k) => {
    const theValue = value[val];
    return (<h4 key={k}>{theValue}</h4>)
    })
}
```

`Object.keys(value)` will return you an array of all the object's keys.  You then need to get the value (`value[val]`).